# How to set up Jenkins on AppFog?

Tags: deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration, appfog

I uploaded Jenkins on AppFog, however I get an error:

```
Unable to create the home directory '/nonexistent/.jenkins'. This is most likely a         permission problem.

To change the home directory, use JENKINS_HOME environment variable or set the JENKINS_HOME system property.
```

What value should I set JENKINS_HOME environment variable to?

Comment: Hi @evodevo, I'm also trying to install Jenkins on Appfog, did you succeed with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add another folder to your Jenkins instance's directory and set it as your JENKINS_HOME. You received the above error because AppFog does not want to grant access to directories outside of the web root.